# no se puede convertir de 'int' a 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity3d, unity

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][![necesito ayuda me dice el error del titulo y nose como es la forma de hacer el vector3]

estoy tratando de hacer que un personaje se mueva en unity si me podrian ayudar muchas gracias <3

Comment: te esta diciendo que vos le queres para un dato de tipo int a un metodo que no acepta int. y coloca bien las etiquetas, no es c++ sino c#, no es dev, solo visual studio, y que problema tenes con array que colocaste esa etiqueta?

Answer (score 1):

A ver si te puedo ayudar un poco con tu problema y darte un par de consejos...

Lo primero es que tal y como te ha indicado Ramiro Barone estas intentando almacenar un tipo de variable, en este caso un int en otro tipo de variable no preparada para ello como es el Vector3. La variable Vector3 contiene dentro de ella 3 componentes (x, y, z) representando cada una de ellas una posición en el espacio 3D de Unity. Puedes modificar el valor de cada componente del Vector3 individualmente de la siguiente forma:

```
Vector3 myVector = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
myVector.x = 1;
myVector.y = 5;
myVector.z = 20;
```

O si quieres setear las 3 componentes a la vez puedes usar el método Set() de la siguiente forma:

```
Vector3 myVector = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
myVector.Set(1, 5, 20);
```

Por otra parte un par de consejos que te doy que no se si conocerás sobre Unity pero me han llamado la atención por lo que has dicho. Por lo que comentas estas intentando mover un personaje, si es el caso te recomiendo darle un vistazo a los componentes RigidBody y CharacterController de Unity y que sobretodo evites usar los metodos Translate y position de Unity. Ambos métodos son **teletransportes** y al usarlos estas haciendo que el motor ignore las colisiones lo que te comportara que tu personaje atraviese el suelo o paredes por ejemplo.

Los componentes que te he comentado (te recomiendo en especial CharacterController) tienen métodos propios para desplazar un objeto usando las físicas del motor y teniendo en cuentas las colisiones y formas del terreno ahorrándote mucho trabajo.

Te dejo aquí la documentación oficial de Unity con ejemplos para mover objetos tanto para el RigidBody como el CharacterController:

Character Controller: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html

RigidBody: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html

Comment: muchisimas gracias por la ayuda, ahora voy a poner en practica eso. hace unos dias estuve viendo eso de que el metodo no es el indicado para hacer que se mueva. tambien lei sobre el character controller que es mejor. y con respecto a lo de Ramiro Barone ahora lo cambio pasa que soy nuevo en esto y no entendia mucho jaja gracias por la ayuda